# How can I see all the projects I'm watching on github?

Tags: github

Is there a way to see a list of all projects I'm watching and maybe unwatch some in bulk?

Comment: As an addition, here is the official answer by GitHub: [Listing watched repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/listing-watched-repositories/)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

- Make sure you're logged in and go to **[https://github.com/watching](https://github.com/login?return_to=https://github.com/watching)**
- Profit! ;-)

More information about this and related features can be in the official **[announcement](https://github.blog/2012-08-06-notifications-stars/)**

[image: watched]

Comment: Thanks! Their help search needs to be updated to include this.

Comment: Thanks.. This is one of the most unintuitive places for watched repos.

Comment: in 2020, you click the top right bell, then on the left `Manage notifications` then `Watched Repositories`.

Comment: How to see partially watched repos', i..e with lower ranked notifications (as there are now several options to be notified on watching subscription)?

Answer (score 40):

As commented by @xinthose, things have changed in 2020, including the fact we now have starred repos (which is often what you really want) and also different levels of watching.

For watched repos do the following (or enter URL `https://github.com/watching` as @nulltoken suggests). You will then wee your Watched repositories grouped by type of watch.

1. Click on the bell in the upper right

[image: github bell]

2. Select the *Manage notifications* in the lower left and then *Watched repositories*

[image]

For Starred repositories, click your avatar in the upper right and then select *Your stars*.

[image: avatar menu]

Comment: It looks like a physical inbox tray now.

Comment: thanks.. for me that was more valuable than nulltokens answer

Comment: In 2020, things are a bit different. See the comment by @xinthose responding to the accepted answer above.